# Frozen cryptography.SE chat room

Tags: support, chat

Our [cryptography lounge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/784/cryptography) has been frozen due to inactivity. I feel it is important it be revived, but after some searching on MSO it appears only moderators can unfreeze rooms. Can we reopen the room?

Answer (score 2):

I've unfrozen the room.  Any moderator on any site may perform this action if it happens again in the future.  You'll usually find one of us in [The Assembly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly).

Remember that actual user messages (not just feeds) are needed to keep a room warm.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I posted a message there, but I am not sure if that unfroze the room.

Comment: Mine still says it's frozen.

Comment: Yes, it still says "*This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added.*" for me too.

Comment: Moderators can post in a frozen room, that doesn't unfreeze the room. You need to go to the room info page and unfreeze.